# Getting userNo of a caller or calling entity

Tags: android, sinch

I am using **sinch services** in my android app and using mobile number as userID now. I want to know Suppose I am inside some activity and I want to ***get the number*** of other person he can be a ***caller or receiver***. So can we get that number in

> "As we have given to the sinch"

not in Return type **"Call"** but it should be same as we have given to Sinch like this "8888888888" so I should get this in my activity

**Purpose :** **Same** Feedback form for both receiver and caller will be created as soon as the call **ends**. So caller will **rate** receiver and *vice versa*.  So I have to give the other **person's number** to the api to update rating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK I have Solved my own problem by using call.getRemoteUserId(); in callscreenactivity